# jenkins-cli build trigger connection times out for long running jobs

Tags: connection-timeout, jenkins-cli

I use the followig command from udeploy Shell step to invoke a Jenkins job. I need to wait for the job to finish and then continue with further steps in udeploy.

Irrespective of whether i invoke the jenkins job directly from a shell on the server or from a Shell step in Udeploy, the problem is the same.

Cmd:-
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s  -remoting build  -s --username  --password ''

Output of short running jobs ( few mins )

```
Aug 03, 2018 3:55:09 PM hudson.cli.CLI _main
WARNING: Failed to authenticate with your SSH keys. Proceeding as anonymous
Started Job » SleepJob #4
Completed Job #4 : SUCCESS
```

Output of long running jobs (Not sure exactly where it fails, but have noticed this for a job running for an hour)
*Jenkins job finishes fine
*The status returned to the shell is this

```
Aug 03, 2018 11:42:53 AM hudson.cli.CLI _main
WARNING: Failed to authenticate with your SSH keys. Proceeding as anonymous
Started Job #1
Aug 03, 2018 1:54:36 PM hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread run
SEVERE: I/O error in channel CLI connection to <URL>
java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out (Read failed)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
        at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:114)
        at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:239)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
        at hudson.remoting.FlightRecorderInputStream.read(FlightRecorderInputStream.java:91)
        at hudson.remoting.ChunkedInputStream.readHeader(ChunkedInputStream.java:72)
        at hudson.remoting.ChunkedInputStream.readUntilBreak(ChunkedInputStream.java:103)
        at hudson.remoting.ChunkedCommandTransport.readBlock(ChunkedCommandTransport.java:39)
        at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:35)
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:63)
hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out (Read failed)
        at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:329)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:992)
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:96)
        Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to CLI connection to <URL>
                at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1693)
                at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:192)
                at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:907)
                at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:281)
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.main(Unknown Source)
                at hudson.cli.CLI.execute(CLI.java:380)
                at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:644)
                at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:426)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out (Read failed)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
        at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:114)
        at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:239)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
        at hudson.remoting.FlightRecorderInputStream.read(FlightRecorderInputStream.java:91)
        at hudson.remoting.ChunkedInputStream.readHeader(ChunkedInputStream.java:72)
        at hudson.remoting.ChunkedInputStream.readUntilBreak(ChunkedInputStream.java:103)
        at hudson.remoting.ChunkedCommandTransport.readBlock(ChunkedCommandTransport.java:39)
        at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:35)
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:63)
```

For test purpose, there is no idle time even set on the slave configuration.

The error message is thrown 12 mins after the jenkins job finishes. Even if the job would take 4 hrs, it executes the job successfully and at the end it throws the error.

If there is a connectivity drop, then the error would appear when the problem happens and not always after the job finishes.

What should i check in network/firewall to fix this ? We do not have any specific port set for the slave connection.

tcpdump is very large for larger duration to check when eactly it drops. 
What are some better ways to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there's something between your Jenkins master and slave that's disconnecting your session. Either that or your slave is going unresponsive in the middle of your build. I've had Jenkins builds going for up to 24 hours without an issue, there isn't any strict limit on the length of a build.

If I had to guess you've got a VPN tunnel or NAT gateway between your master and slave and since the build isn't reporting anything to the master nothing is getting sent. VPN's and NAT gateway's will routinely end connections that don't send any data in a given interval to clear out their connection tables. SSH has a keepalive feature built in to get around this.

On your build slave try [setting the following](https://patrickmn.com/aside/how-to-keep-alive-ssh-sessions/) in /etc/ssh/ssh_config (assuming you're using openssh):

```
ServerAliveInterval 300
```

This will tell your slave to send a no_op packet every 5 minutes just to make sure intermediate network equipment won't end your connection on you.

It doesn't look like [Jenkins supports setting keepalive on the master side yet](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25793).

Comment: Thank you, I will test this and let you know

Comment: This setting helped. Thank you for the support.